# How to reduce the size of the lambda (to reduce cold start time) >> Could we use layers?

Tags: aws-lambda, aws-cdk

I am a bit concerned by the size of my lambda functions, a 34 lines of Typescript turned into a 12,2 Mb when I look for it in the console ...
I triied to minimize imports, and make them selective.

For example in this very function the import are:
`import { EventBridge } from 'aws-sdk'`

Any clues Welcome

Comment: do not include 'aws-sdk' when deploying lambda. AWS already has this module baked in...so you should have it has a devdependecy

Answer (score 0):

If the size of the lambda is because of the library imported, layers would be the best option. It would also help if you are using the library in different lambdas. You have to just add the layers to that lambda. But checkout the structure of the zip file which you need to upload for layers. that sometimes give error.

Answer (score 0):

Bundling `aws-sdk` takes up to **7 MB** when zipped. You should not bundle it unless you have specific reasons. It is already available in the Lambda runtime.

An easy way would be doing smth like:

```
zip --quiet -r --exclude="node_modules/aws-sdk/*" \
  artifact.zip \
  lib node_modules
```

I've described this, and 2 other easy steps to reduce Lambda artifact size [in my article here](https://vladholubiev.medium.com/3x-smaller-lambda-artifacts-by-removing-junk-from-node-modules-2b50780ca1f5).